# Writing best GridSearch classifiers into a table

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I found and successfully tested following script that applies Pipeline and GridSearchCV to classifier selection. The script outputs the best classifier and its accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_train = iris.data
y_train = iris.target
X_test = iris.data[:10] # Augmenting test data
y_test = iris.target[:10] # Augmenting test data

#Create a pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('classifier', LogisticRegression())])

# Create space of candidate learning algorithms and their hyperparameters
search_space = [{'classifier': [LogisticRegression()],
                 'classifier__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
                 'classifier__C': np.logspace(0, 4, 10)},
                {'classifier': [RandomForestClassifier()],
                 'classifier__n_estimators': [10, 100, 1000],
                 'classifier__max_features': [1, 2, 3]}]

# Create grid search 
clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, search_space, cv=5, verbose=0)

# Fit grid search
best_model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Best training accuracy: %.3f' % best_model.best_score_)
print('Best estimator:', best_model.best_estimator_.get_params()['classifier'])
# Predict on test data with best params
y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)
# Test data accuracy of model with best params
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, digits=4))
print('Test set accuracy score for best params: %.3f' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, 
average='weighted'))
```

How can I adjust the script so that it not only outputs the best classifier, which is LogReg in our example, but also the best selected among the other classifiers? Above, I like to see the output from `RandomForestClassifier()`, too.

Ideal is a solution where the best classifier for each algorithm (LogReg, RandomForest,..) is shown and where each of those best classifiers is sorted into a table. The first column or index should be the model and `precision_recall_fscore_support` values are in rows on the right. The table should then be sorted by F-score.

PS: Though the script works, I'm yet unsure what the function of `LogisticRegression()` in the Pipeline is, as it's defined in the search space later.

**Solution (simplified):**

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_train = iris.data
y_train = iris.target
X_test = iris.data[:10]
y_test = iris.target[:10]

seed=1
models = [
            'RFC',
            'logisticRegression'
         ]
clfs = [
        RandomForestClassifier(random_state=seed,n_jobs=-1),
        LogisticRegression()
        ]

params = {
            models[0]:{'n_estimators':[100]},
            models[1]: {'C':[1000]}
         }


for name, estimator in zip(models,clfs):

    print(name)

    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator, params[name], scoring='accuracy', refit='True', n_jobs=-1, cv=5)

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("best params: " + str(clf.best_params_))
    print("best scores: " + str(clf.best_score_))

    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

    print("Accuracy: {:.4%}".format(acc))
    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, digits=4))
```

Comment: @Cristopher, Hope my answer helps

Answer (score 2):

### If I understood correctly, this should work fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(list(best_model.cv_results_['params']))
ranking = best_model.cv_results_['rank_test_score']
# The sorting is done based on the test_score of the models.
sorting = np.argsort(best_model.cv_results_['rank_test_score'])

# Sort the lines based on the ranking of the models
df_final = df.iloc[sorting]

# The first line contains the best model and its parameters
df_final.to_csv('sorted_table.csv')

# OR to avoid the index in the writting 
df_final.to_csv('sorted_table2.csv',index=False)
```

---

**Results**:

[image: See here]

---

However, in this case, **the ordering is not done based on the F values**. To do so use this. Define in the `GridSearch` the `scoring` attribute to `f1_weighted` and repeat my code.

---

**Example**:

```
...
clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, search_space, cv=5, verbose=0,scoring='f1_weighted')

best_model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(best_model.cv_results_['params']))
ranking = best_model.cv_results_['rank_test_score']

# The sorting is done based on the F values of the models.
sorting = np.argsort(best_model.cv_results_['rank_test_score'])

# Sort the lines based on the ranking of the models
df_final = df.iloc[sorting]

df_final.to_csv('F_sorted_table.csv')
```

---

**Results**:
[image: Here]

---

Comment: Thank you. It's almost the answer, I guess. For the example above, I would only expect two rows: Logistic Regression and then RandomForest, each with their best model and result. I thought that the models could maybe written into a dict and afterwards the best result for each dict element would be called. I tried but had several syntax problems.

Comment: hello. you can then filter df_final pandas dataframe in order to keep the first Logistic and first RandomForest found in the second column.